# Where can I ask a question about identifying encoded data?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I need help identifying the type of a piece of encoded data, which site should I go to?

I guess Cryptography is not the right place to go.

Comment: There is not enough info to answer this.

Comment: What does encoded mean here? A bunch of bytes can be ASCII, UTF8 or EBCIDIC encoded. Or maybe base64 encoded. Is that what you ask about? Or do you mean a bunch of bytes that is Encrypted? What do you expect as an answer in that case? If it is encrypted with AES, Blowfish, etc? Or do you expect us to decrypt the piece of data? In which case we need the private key.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sadly, I don't think there's any site in the network which accepts a question like this. They do get asked frequently, up to a point where sites like the [Cryptography](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/tour) Stack Exchange site even have [a community-specific close reason](https://crypto.meta.stackexchange.com/q/100/24869) for them. The linked topic does not even mention alternative resources for you, perhaps because there aren't any.

The underlying reason is that Stack Exchange aims to build a library of *reusable* questions & answers, i.e. the question ideally is useful for future readers with the same problem. This is never the case for questions like 'here's my encoded data, please decode it'; those are only useful for the author. It doesn't help that they're often showing zero effort and research; I recall seeing one where the author came with what they thought was uncrackable code, but it was just the [Base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) version of the plain text.

Also quite often, they're simply unanswerable without knowing the (usually private) key required for decryption. After all, that's the very point of encryption; if you could go to the Internet and get the plain text back, it wouldn't be real encryption, would it? Even getting back metadata (whether it's an image, sound or just text) would defeat the very purpose of encryption.

Comment: 'private key using for encryption' -> 'private key required for decryption'

Comment: @MartinJames that was written with the idea of using a private key for encryption and a (corresponding but not known) key for decryption.